# C# how to read lines then delete line when found specified word

Tags: c#, xml

Im writing this in C#, I need my program to read a (large) XML file, search for a specific word ('Implements') and then delete every line where this word is present. But a bit confused as to how to go about it. This is what I have so far. Does anyone know what to use instead of what Im hoping 'Deleteline' would do, Im very new to coding. thanks!

```
    using System;
    using System.Xml;

namespace XMLReadAndParse
{
    class XMLReadandParse
    {
      
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("CaxtonFx.FirebirdApi.xml");
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if(line.Contains("Implements"))
        {
            var text = line.Contains("Implements");
            result = text.Deleteline();  //I know this doesn't work but not sure how to proceed 
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
    }
}
```

Comment: What about creating a new file, add each line you find `implements` and delete the XML afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. You cannot delete lines from the file you are reading.

You can however, create a new file, write the lines you need to the new file, delete the original file, and rename the new file to the old file.

I wrote a small and simple example using your code above, I have also tested it for you. All passed my side :)

```
        var originalFile = "CaxtonFx.FirebirdApi.xml";
        var tempFile = "TempXmlFile.xml";

        var file = File.Create(tempFile);

        file.Close();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(originalFile);
        var newLines = new List<string>();

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (!line.Contains("Implements"))
            {
                newLines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        File.WriteAllText(tempFile, String.Join(Environment.NewLine, newLines));

        File.Delete(originalFile);
        File.Move(tempFile, originalFile);
```

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Happy coding!